# AWS Cloudwatch: Update custom metric value

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

Is there a way to update the value of a custom metric in AWS Cloudwatch for a given timestamp?

E.g. I have a metric with number of errors in a log file every hour. Now I want to update this metric every minute to get live data on a dashboard. So basically I want to run something like this with an updated "--value" every minute.

```
aws cloudwatch put-metric-data --metric-name Errors --namespace MyApp --value 2 --timestamp $(date --utc  +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:00:00.000Z")
```

Comment: No, there is no such way.

Comment: For this specific case, where the value will be equal or grow (number of errors) I achieved my purpose by using the above command and setting statistics to "maximum" when graphing the result.